# Swift: Firebase updateChildValues function Overwriting and Deleting Other Keys at Location

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running into a peculiar issue when trying to simultaneously **update** values at different JSON branches in Firebase. The method provided in the documentation is perfect when it comes to creating new data,

```
 let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
 let post = ["uid": userID,
             "author": username,
             "title": title,
             "body": body]
 let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
 ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

but when I try to update data at multiple locations, it overwrites the other keys as if I was using `setValue`. Here is my code.

```
 let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    userRef = Database.database().reference()

   let vehicle = ["make":make.text,
                   "model": model.text,
                   "year":year.text,
                   "color":color.text,
                   "doors":doors.text]
    let driver = ["currentEvent":eventID]
    let childUpdates = ["/users/\(userID!)": driver,
                        "/status/\(userID!)/driverInfo/vehicle": vehicle]
    userRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

I have also attached a picture which shows which data is and isn't being deleted when the function is executed.

[image: Image revealing the data which is deleted]

I believe what I am trying to do is possible, and from what I understand the whole purpose of `updateChildValues` is so that other children aren't overwritten.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are updating the objects with objects like this:

```
let childUpdates = ["/users/\(userID!)": driver,
                        "/status/\(userID!)/driverInfo/vehicle": vehicle]
```

You are giving the object (a dictionary) as the value of the `childUpdates` dictionary. What this does is that replace all the children with this object meaning deleting the values for which you are sending nil for example in your case you have not included `info` or `infoThat` .

Now if you want to change only the values you want to give like only change the value of say `make` and `model` for `vehicle` and `currentEvent` for `driver` , you have to give the particular path for these values

```
["/users/\(userID!)/currentEvent": eventID,
                        "/status/\(userID!)/driverInfo/vehicle/make": make.text, "/status/\(userID!)/driverInfo/vehicle/model": model.text]
```

I think this will update the values of these locations as you expected.

HTH...

Comment: Thank you! Seems to me like Firebase should either allow selective updates at multiple locations (like the name suggests), or just change the name from `updateChildValues`, since currently it is more like `setValue`.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is bit of confusing , I had to read the doucumentation to understand the  behaviour.You can check it here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am mistaken, but if I understand what you're trying to do this might yield better results?

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    userRef = Database.database().reference()

   let vehicle = ["make":make.text,
                   "model": model.text,
                   "year":year.text,
                   "color":color.text,
                   "doors":doors.text]
    let driver = ["currentEvent":eventID]
    let childUpdates = ["/users/": userID!),
                        "/status/\(userID!)/driverInfo": vehicle]
    userRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```